# Python regular expression not giving expected result

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Trying to do a regular expression search on a list in python 2.5.4 - example code:

```
import re

list_in = ['heti_abcd_xyz_1234', 'heti_abcd_xyz', 'heti_abcd']

en = re.compile('abcd_xyz_1234$')

for item in list_in:
    if en.search(item) is None:
        list_in.remove(item)
print list_in
```

For the result however I get:

```
['heti_abcd_xyz_1234', 'heti_abcd']
```

when I'm expecting only the first element.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Use [`.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) instead of a regexp which is overkill for this check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're modifying the list as you iterate over it. You can't do that.

Comment: Thanks, Falmarri. I did have a line like list_out = list_in - which seemed to still show the problem. = must make a reference rather than a new object in python it seems?

Comment: @TZHX: Yes, that's how python works. Variables are just names. You'll need to do list_out = list_in[:] to get a copy. Although list comprehension as posted in other answers is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a lot simpler:

```
>>> list_in = ['heti_abcd_xyz_1234', 'heti_abcd_xyz', 'heti_abcd']
>>> [x for x in list_in if x.endswith("abcd_xyz_1234")]
['heti_abcd_xyz_1234']
```

If you want a solution that works for arbitrary regex, you can do:

```
pattern = re.compile("your_regex")
new_list = [x for x in list_in if pattern.search(x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a list while iterating over it. Simply create a new one:

```
import re
list_in = ['heti_abcd_xyz_1234', 'heti_abcd_xyz', 'heti_abcd']
en = re.compile('abcd_xyz_1234$')
new_list = [item for item in list_in if en.search(item) is not None]
print new_list
```

Btw, use [`.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) instead of a regex unless the regex in your code is just an example for something more complex.